# what is biological mass of rhinovirus in adult

Tags: common-cold

I've read wikipedia and did some web searches, but could not find that info.

1) what is mass of single rhinovirus?
2) what is average quantity of rhinovirus during peak of common cold in adult human body?

Comment: 1)Why you want to know rhino virus mass? 2) INFECTIOUS DOSE: The infectious dose depends on the strain/type of the virus, and ranges from 0.032 - 0.4 TCID50 when inoculated as nasal spray, and 0.68 TCID50 through aerosol particles(ref:msd manual) but during peak periods the level will start to fall as the body's immune system fights

Comment: @ Physicsapproval, like in wiki for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_body : "Of the 70 kg weight of an average human body, nearly 25 kg is non-human cells or non-cellular material such as bone and connective tissue." I think knowing mass of virus can give us some perspective.

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov Most of this ‘extra’ mass you are referring to is single-celled organisms such as bacteria on our skin and inside our gut it airways. Viruses are many orders of magnitude lighter (approx 1x10e-17 kg). They are so small that they require mass spectrometry or electron microscopy to *weigh* them, and the weight is usually expressed in multiples of atomic mass units (Daltons or Da). For example: 100 MDa is the approx mass of a [bacteriophage virus](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/362/6417/918).